# Nouns and Gerunds

Tags: nouns

Why does it sound 'right' to say - "Enjoy your reading", "Enjoy your fishing", "Enjoy your hunting" - but 'wrong' to say - "Enjoy your eating", "Enjoy your sleeping" ?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Only those don't sound right.  Enjoy your book.  Have fun fishing.  Enjoy your hunting trip.

Comment: Enjoy your meal (breakfast, lunch, dinner) and enjoy your sleep are more idiomatic.